# undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ZeroFieldsBase`

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am using protobuf in my project, and for "typical" protobuf messages, everything is working fine.

However, I have just created a new `.proto` definition, which is of a message *without any fields.*

```
syntax = "proto2";
package proj.cfg;

message Foo
{
    enum Type
    {
        ONE = 1;
        TWO = 2;
        THREE = 3;
    }
}
```

The `protoc` compiler happily generates the message definition, and I am building it in my code and linking against the protobuf libfrary

```
/usr/bin/c++ ... CMakeFiles/foo_test.dir/foo_test.cpp.o -o foo_test 
             ... /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a ...
```

However, the program fails to link, with an undefined reference error

```
...
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_bases.h:67:
   undefined reference to `vtable for google::protobuf::internal::ZeroFieldsBase'
```

I have found the following comment [in the protobuf source here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/generated_message_bases.h):

> ```
> // To save code size, protos without any fields are derived from 
> // ZeroFieldsBase rather than Message.
> ```

If I add a "fake" field into my `Foo` message, it will now derive from `Message` instead of `ZeroFieldsBase`, and now my program links

```
syntax = "proto2";
package proj.cfg;

message Foo
{
    enum Type
    {
        ONE = 1;
        TWO = 2;
        THREE = 3;
    }
    optional Type type = 1; // fake field to make the app link
}
```

I built the protobuf library myself from source (version 21.1), and the only option I passed to `configure` was `--prefix /usr/local`.

**Question:**

I am linking against `libprotobuf.a`, and protobuf classes which derive from `google::protobuf::Message` link fine.

Those which derive from `google::protobuf::ZeroFieldsBase` cannot link.

What do I need to do to link against `ZeroFieldsBase`?

Comment: Hi, I face the exact same problem. Did you find a proper way to fix that ? I'm trying with version `3.21.12` of protobuf.

Comment: No, unfortunately only the fake field workaround I mentioned before